# How to avoid floating point precision errors with floats or doubles in Java?

Tags: java, sum, floating-accuracy

I have aproblem with long sums of floats or doubles in Java.

If I execute:

```
for ( float value = 0.0f; value < 1.0f; value += 0.1f )
    System.out.println( value );
```

I get:

```
0.0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.70000005
0.8000001
0.9000001
```

How do I get rid of the accumulation of the floating precision error?

I tried using doubles to halve the error, but the result is the same.

Comment: Closely related is this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699066/in-which-order-should-floats-be-added-to-get-the-most-precise-result

Comment: I don’t agree with the closing of this question, as the answers have useful Java-specific information and code examples that the supposed “duplicate” does not. Unfortunately I’m outnumbered by the others who want almost all floating point questions directed to the main general one. See [discussion on meta here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427161/can-we-reopen-this-javascript-specific-question-about-floating-point-precision-t).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is a no exact representation of 0.1 as a `float` or `double`. Because of this representation error the results are slightly different from what you expected.

A couple of approaches you can use:

- When using the `double` type, only display as many digits as you need. When checking for equality allow for a small tolerance either way.
- Alternatively use a type that allows you to store the numbers you are trying to represent exactly, for example `BigDecimal` can represent 0.1 exactly.

Example code for `BigDecimal`:

```
BigDecimal step = new BigDecimal("0.1");
for (BigDecimal value = BigDecimal.ZERO;
     value.compareTo(BigDecimal.ONE) < 0;
     value = value.add(step)) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

See it online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/7fKju)

Answer (score 11):

Don't use float/double in an iterator as this maximises your rounding error.  If you just use the following

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    System.out.println(i / 10.0);
```

it prints

```
0.0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
```

I know BigDecimal is a popular choice, but I prefer double not because its much faster but its usually much shorter/cleaner to understand.

If you count the number of symbols as a measure of code complexity

- using double => 11 symbols
- use BigDecimal (from @Mark Byers example) => 21 symbols

BTW: don't use float unless there is a *really* good reason to not use double.

Answer (score 10):

You can avoid this specific problem using classes like [`BigDecimal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). `float` and `double`, being IEEE 754 floating-point, are not designed to be perfectly accurate, they're designed to be fast. But note Jon's point below: `BigDecimal` can't represent "one third" accurately, any more than `double` can represent "one tenth" accurately. But for (say) financial calculations, `BigDecimal` and classes like it tend to be the way to go, because they can represent numbers in the way that we humans tend to think about them.

Comment: It's not a matter of "precise" and "imprecise" - it's a matter of what can be represented in each type. BigDecimal is no more capable of representing "a third" exactly than double is capable of representing "a tenth" exactly.

Comment: @Jon: Actually, as you commented I was editing, I'd said "precise" where I meant "accurate" (because everyone does, but I try to avoid doing it). Fascinating point about "a third", though. **Very** good point indeed.

Comment: I'd say that "accurate" isn't necessarily a good word either. There are two issues here - one is base representation, and the other is a fixed or varying size (where BigDecimal can expand as it sees fit depending on the MathContext, whereas something like System.Decimal in .NET is always 128 bits). But it's definitely a complicated thing to describe concisely :) "Accurate" may or may not be appropriate for BigDecimal based on the MathContext used - I *believe* that with an "unlimited", operations will throw an exception if the result can't be represented exactly.

Answer (score 4):

It's *not* just an accumulated error (and has absolutely nothing to do with Java). `1.0f`, once translated to actual code, does not have the value 0.1 - you already get a rounding error.

From [The Floating-Point Guide:](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

> What can I do to avoid this problem?
>
> That depends on what kind of
>   calculations you’re doing.
>
> - If you really need your results to add up exactly, especially when you work with money: use a special decimal datatype.
> - If you just don’t want to see all those extra decimal places: simply format your result rounded to a fixed
>     number of decimal places when
>     displaying it.
> - If you have no decimal datatype available, an alternative is to work
>     with integers, e.g. do money
>     calculations entirely in cents. But
>     this is more work and has some
>     drawbacks.

Read the linked-to site for detailed information.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to forgo `==` and check if the two values are *close enough*. (I know this is not what you asked in the body but I'm answering the question title.)

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness I recommend this one:

Shewchuck, "Robust Adaptive Floating-Point Geometric Predicates", if you want more examples of how to perform exact arithmetic with floating point - or at least controlled accuracy which is the original intention of author, http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/papers/robustr.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You should use a decimal datatype, not floats:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Comment: @anivaler The link was broken from the beginning. Java 1.4 was long dead when this answer was posted.

Answer (score 2):

I had faced same issue, resolved the same using BigDecimal. Below is the snippet which helped me.

```
double[] array = {45.34d, 45000.24d, 15000.12d, 4534.89d, 3444.12d, 12000.00d, 4900.00d, 1800.01d};
double total = 0.00d;
BigDecimal bTotal = new BigDecimal(0.0+"");
for(int i = 0;i < array.length; i++) {
    total += (double)array[i];
    bTotal = bTotal.add(new BigDecimal(array[i] +""));
}
System.out.println(total);
System.out.println(bTotal);
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
package loopinamdar;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class loopinam {
    static DecimalFormat valueFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.0");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (float value = 0.0f; value < 1.0f; value += 0.1f)
            System.out.println("" + valueFormat.format(value));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First make it a **double**. Don't ever use *float* or you will have trouble using the `java.lang.Math` utilities.

Now if you happen to know in advance the **precision** you want and it is equal or less than 15, then it becomes easy to tell your *double*s to behave. Check below:

```
// the magic method:
public final static double makePrecise(double value, int precision) {
    double pow = Math.pow(10, precision);
    long powValue = Math.round(pow * value);
    return powValue / pow;
}
```

Now whenever you make an operation, you must tell your *double* result to behave:

```
for ( double value = 0.0d; value < 1.0d; value += 0.1d )
            System.out.println( makePrecise(value, 1) + " => " + value );
```

Output:

```
0.0 => 0.0
0.1 => 0.1
0.2 => 0.2
0.3 => 0.30000000000000004
0.4 => 0.4
0.5 => 0.5
0.6 => 0.6
0.7 => 0.7
0.8 => 0.7999999999999999
0.9 => 0.8999999999999999
1.0 => 0.9999999999999999
```

If you need more than 15 precision then you are out of luck:

```
for ( double value = 0.0d; value < 1.0d; value += 0.1d )
            System.out.println( makePrecise(value, 16) + " => " + value );
```

Output:

```
0.0 => 0.0
0.1 => 0.1
0.2 => 0.2
0.3000000000000001 => 0.30000000000000004
0.4 => 0.4
0.5 => 0.5
0.6 => 0.6
0.7 => 0.7
0.8 => 0.7999999999999999
0.9 => 0.8999999999999999
0.9999999999999998 => 0.9999999999999999
```

**NOTE1:** For performance you should cache the `Math.pow` operation in an array. Not done here for clarity.

**NOTE2:** That's why we never use *double*s for prices, but *long*s where the last N (i.e. where N <= 15, usually 8) digits are the decimal digits. Then you can forget about what I wrote above :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep on using `float` and avoid accumulating errors by repeatedly adding `0.1f`, try something like this:

```
for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++) {
    float value = 0.1f * count;
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Note however, as others have already explained, that `float` is not an infinitely precise data type.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to be aware of the precision required in your calculation and the precision your chosen data type is capable of and present your answers accordingly.

For example, if you are dealing with numbers with 3 significant figures, use of `float` (which provides a precision of 7 significant figures) is appropriate. However, you can't quote your final answer to a precision of 7 significant figures if your starting values only have a precision of 2 significant figures.

```
5.01 + 4.02 = 9.03 (to 3 significant figures)
```

In your example you are performing multiple additions, and with each addition there is a consequent impact on the final precision.