# What is the most accurate way to count a sum of vector elements using std::accumulate?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, accumulate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ float precision question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699066/c-float-precision-question)

I've got a problem of determining the most precise method of the three to calculate the sum of vector elements, which can be only positive numbers, using std::accumulate.

1)

```
double sum(vector<float> &v)
{
     return accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0);
}
```

2)

```
double sum(vector<float> &v)
{
     sort(v.begin(), v.end());
     return accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0);
}
```

3)

```
double sum(vector<float> &v)
{
     sort(v.begin(), v.end(), greater<float>());
     return accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0);
}
```

This is a kind of job interview question, that's why I got these particular three ways to calculate the sum. I've done a lot of searching the web, but couldn't figure out the difference. Could you please help me guys understand it?

Comment: What do you mean by, "a kind of job interview question"? Are you asking for help to pass a job interview?

Comment: Sort by absolute value and start at the small end. You can think about why that is.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos No, I'm not asking to pass a job interview. This task was once at a job interview, so I'm just preparing for a job interview, doing different tasks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference should be really small, but starting with the smaller numbers will be slightly more accurate. Consider for exposition purposes that your floating point number contained only 4 significant digits and an exponent, and that it was decimal rather than binary. Using the numbers:

```
a = 5000
b = 5000
c = 1000e4 (10000000)
```

If we add `c` first, then either `a` or `b`, the smaller of the two falls off the representation and is rounded. The end result of `c` + `b` + `a` will yield `1000e4`. If on the other hand, we add `a` and `b` first we get `1e4` as the first intermediate value, and adding that to `c` will yield `1001e4` which is a more precise result for the operation.

Comment: The difference can be *huge*, just look at the benchmark in the other question.