# Elixir Unexpected Floating Point Result Difference Between Enum.Sum and My Custom Sum Function

Tags: floating-point, elixir

As a homework, I've implemented the following `sum` function to return the sum of a list of numbers:

```
defmodule Homework do
  @spec sum(list(number())) :: number()
  def sum(l) do
    case l do
      [] -> 0
      [a | as] -> a + sum(as)
    end
  end
end
```

And as a unit test I've used the following comparison:

```
[-2, -2.1524700989447303, 1] |> fn(l) -> Enum.sum(l) === Homework.sum(l) end.()
```

And this test fails, returning `false`. When I ran the functions in `iex` I got the following result, which is surprising for me:

```
iex(1)> [-2, -2.1524700989447303, 1] |> Enum.sum
-3.1524700989447307
iex(2)> [-2, -2.1524700989447303, 1] |> Homework.sum
-3.1524700989447303
```

What is more, both functions consistently generate `-3.1524700989447307` and `-3.1524700989447303`, respectively.

Why does this difference happens?

**Edit**

The question [Why does changing the sum order returns a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820297/why-does-changing-the-sum-order-returns-a-different-result) pointed me in the right direction but I think that the actual answer to this question (an implementation detail in OTP) could be interesting to someone as well.

Comment: I think it's order: `[-2, -2.1524700989447303, 1] |> Enum.reverse |> Enum.sum` generates `-3.1524700989447303`

Comment: @denis.peplin ??? that's unexpected :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does changing the sum order returns a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820297/why-does-changing-the-sum-order-returns-a-different-result)

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question [Why does changing the sum order returns a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820297/why-does-changing-the-sum-order-returns-a-different-result) inspired me go to the source to see how the implementation was and, surely enough, when the parameter is a  [`list`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html) it uses [Erlang's implementation of `foldl`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/lists.erl), which applies the function in the order *head + accumulator* instead of *accumulator + head* like in my implementation:

https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex

```
@spec sum(t) :: number
def sum(enumerable) do
  reduce(enumerable, 0, &+/2)
end

@spec reduce(t, any, (element, any -> any)) :: any
def reduce(enumerable, acc, fun) when is_list(enumerable) do
  :lists.foldl(fun, acc, enumerable)
end
```

https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/lists.erl

```
-spec foldl(Fun, Acc0, List) -> Acc1 when
      Fun :: fun((Elem :: T, AccIn) -> AccOut),
      Acc0 :: term(),
      Acc1 :: term(),
      AccIn :: term(),
      AccOut :: term(),
      List :: [T],
      T :: term().

foldl(F, Accu, [Hd|Tail]) ->
    foldl(F, F(Hd, Accu), Tail); %% here!
foldl(F, Accu, []) when is_function(F, 2) -> Accu.
```

**Edit**

@Sneftel's comment made me do the following experiment:

```
@spec sum(list(number())) :: number()
def sum(l) do
  case Enum.reverse(l) do # reversing first
    [] -> 0
    [a | as] -> a + sum(as)
  end
end
```

This new version has the same result as `Enum.sum`:

```
iex(1)> Homework.sum([-2, -2.1524700989447303, 1])
-3.1524700989447307
iex(2)> Enum.sum([-2, -2.1524700989447303, 1])
-3.1524700989447307
```

So it seems like it is about the order.

**Edit 2**

Changing `a + sum(as)` to `sum(as) + a` makes no difference in the result when the list not in reverse order.

```
def sum(l) do
  case l do
    [] -> 0
    [a | as] -> sum(as) + a
  end
end

iex(1)> Homework.sum([-2, -2.1524700989447303, 1])
-3.1524700989447303
iex(2)> Enum.sum([-2, -2.1524700989447303, 1])
-3.1524700989447307
```

So when we talk about the relevance of 'order' it is the order in which [folding](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Fold_(higher-order_function)) is happening, not the order of the operands.

Comment: The difference isn't `head+acc` versus `acc+head`. Floating-point addition is commutative, so those two would produce the same results. Rather, the difference is that they're using an accumulator at all. If you haven't learned about "tail recursion" yet, it's worth your time to look into that, to understand why Erlang's approach is much, much more efficient than yours.

Comment: @Sneftel I've made an experiment and it seems like it is about the order... I'll definitely look at 'tail recursion' though, the book I'm reading is about those things :)

Comment: It is about the order, but in the sense of left-folding versus right-folding, not in the sense of the order of operands. Try changing `a + sum(as)` to `sum(as) + a` and you'll see that it has no effect on the result.

Comment: @Sneftel you're right :) . I think I'm in the right mindset now.

Answer (score 3):

I think the real issue here is that one should never expect to do exact equality when working with floating point numbers, because they are inherently imprecise. If precision is needed, then a module such as [`Decimal`](https://hexdocs.pm/decimal/readme.html) can be used.

```
defmodule Homework do
  def sum([]), do: Decimal.new(0)
  def sum([a | as]), do: Decimal.add(a, sum(as))
end
```

Test session:

```
iex(1)> test = [Decimal.new(-2), Decimal.new("-2.1524700989447303"), Decimal.new(1)]
iex(2)> Homework.sum(test) === :lists.foldl(&Decimal.add/2, Decimal.new(0), test)
true
```

[What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://floating-point-gui.de) provides a nice overview of how to effectively work with floating point numbers.