# can i get exactly same sum output in python like matlab

Tags: python, matlab

i am converting a matlab code to python. i found a strange difference of sum of matlab and python. i want to have same output in python like i am getting in matlab. is it possible ?
**in matlab**

> ```
> x = [-200:200]/200;  % 401 values from -200 to 200
> y =sum(x)
> y = 9.9920e-16
> ```

**but in python using different modules i get answer**

> ```
> x = np.arange(-200,201)/200 # 401 values from -200 to 200
> y = np.sum(x)
> y = 1.4210854715202004e-14
> z = sum(x)
> z = -8.43769498715119e-15
> zmath = math.fsum(x)
> zmath = 0.0
> ```

Comment: You are working with IEEE754 floating-point numbers.  You cannot expect absolute accuracy: values will always be approximate.  Your Python and Matlab code snippets both return approximately zero.  'Strange' behaviour like this is perfectly normal.

Comment: so which float values i use to get same output in python,,, just like matlab

Comment: if you just run a for loop and sum them up then we can get same results .... but that will be like sum (x) in matlab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is not the numeric representation but in the order of summation.  You can see this just in Matlab:

```matlab
>> sum(x(randperm(401)))
ans =
   2.7756e-16
>> sum(x(randperm(401)))
ans =
   5.8842e-15
>> sum(x(randperm(401)))
ans =
  -2.2204e-15
```

The order of summation is going to depend on implementation details, e.g., whether the array operation takes advantage of your CPU's vector registers.  If you must have exactly the same result, you'll have to write an explicit loop.  (Based on the answers you got, `z = sum(x)` in Python is doing that internally.)  For more understanding of why this happens, see [Why does changing the sum order returns a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820297/why-does-changing-the-sum-order-returns-a-different-result)

Comment: yes it looks like matlab is not following some defined rules for summing it