# calculating the mean of an array c++

Tags: c++, precision

I encountered a problem when I tried to calculate the mean of an array in two ways. Below is the code:

```
float sum1, sum2, tmp, mean1, mean2;
double sum1_double, sum2_double, tmp_double;
int i, j;
int Nt=29040000;  //array size
int piecesize=32;
int Npiece=Nt/piecesize;
float* img;
float* d_img;
double* img_double;
img_double = (double*)calloc(Nt, sizeof(double));
cudaHostAlloc((void**)&img, sizeof(float)*Nt, cudaHostAllocDefault);
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_img, sizeof(float)*Nt);
...
//Some calculation is done in GPU and the results are stored in d_img;
...    
cudaMemcpy(img, d_img, Nt*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
for (i=0;i<Nt;i++) img_double[i]=(double)img[i];

//Method 1
sum1=0;
for (i=0;i<Nt;i++) 
{ sum1 += img[i]; }

sum1_double=0;
for (i=0;i<Nt;i++) 
{ sum1_double += img_double[i]; }

//Method 2
sum2=0;
for (i=0;i<Npiece;i++)
{   tmp=0; 
      for (j=0;j<piecesize;j++)
        { tmp += img[i*piecesize+j];}
    sum2 += tmp;
}

sum2_double=0;
for (i=0;i<Npiece;i++)
{   tmp_double=0; 
      for (j=0;j<piecesize;j++)
        { tmp_double += img_double[i*piecesize+j];}
    sum2_double += tmp_double;
}

mean1=sum1/(float)Nt;
mean2=sum2/(float)Nt;
mean1_double=sum1_double/(double)Nt;
mean2_double=sum2_double/(double)Nt;

cout<<setprecision(15)<<mean1<<endl;
cout<<setprecision(15)<<mean2<<endl;
cout<<setprecision(15)<<mean1_double<<endl;
cout<<setprecision(15)<<mean2_double<<endl;
```

Output:

> ```
> 132.221862792969
> 129.565872192383
> 129.565938340543
> 129.565938340543
> ```

The results obtained from the two methods, mean1=129.6, mean2=132.2, are significantly different. May I know why?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Why don't you print the sums.

Comment: @6502 Good catch. And even better user name. I miss my Atari.

Comment: "//The array data is stored in img" Show code, not comments.

Comment: I guess a simple fill of `29040000` elements with a for loop would be a good example. Also a simple test case if you set them all to the same value then you can verify that the average is correct for at least that test case..

Comment: maybe this can be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699066/in-which-order-should-floats-be-added-to-get-the-most-precise-result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that floating point arithmetic is not precise. When you accumulate integers, float becomes imprecise when abs(value) becomes larger than 2<sup>24</sup> (I'm supposing IEEE-754 32-bit here). For example, float is incapable to store 16777217 precisely (it will become 16777216 or 16777218, depending on the rounding mode).

Supposedly your second calculation is the more precise one, as less precision is lost, because of the separate `tmp` accumulation.

Change your `sum1`, `sum2`, `tmp` variables to `long long int`, and hopefully you'll get the same result for both calculations.

Note: I've supposed that your `img` stores integer data. If it stores floats, then there is no easy way to fix this perfectly. One way is to use `double` instead of `float` for `sum1`, `sum2` and `tmp`. The difference will be there, but it will be much smaller. And there are techniques how to accumuluate `float`s more precisely than simple summing. Like [Kahan Summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The data in img is `float` type. How can I change it to `long long int`.

Comment: You probably want double then

Comment: @geza Thanks for your information. I have tried using `double` type. As you can see in the updated post, with `double` the results obtained from method 1 and method 2 are the same.

Comment: @drescherjm I have updated my post using double. The results seem to be better. Thanks.

Comment: @JianGao: In the general case, they won't be the same. Even, they may not be exactly the same currently (print the numbers with more precision, like 20 dignificant digits). But maybe the difference is so small, so it's not a problem for you.

Comment: @geza you are right. I have printed more precision. Yes, for my application, method 2 with `float` data type is enough.