# Eigen sum(), colwise().sum().sum() and rowwise().sum().sum() all give different answers

Tags: c++, eigen

I have this example code:

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  Eigen::MatrixXf M = Eigen::MatrixXf::Random(1000, 1000);
  std::cout.precision(17);
  std::cout << M.colwise().sum().sum() << std::endl;
  std::cout << M.rowwise().sum().sum() << std::endl;
  std::cout << M.sum() << std::endl;
}
```

I compile with the following command: (g++ version 7.3, but I have seen this with other compilers too)

```
g++ -O0 -o test -Ieigen-3.3.7 test.cc
```

And the output is

```
13.219823837280273
13.220325469970703
13.217720031738281
```

Shouldn't all these 3 values be the same? I am using no optimizations after all.

Comment: floating point math is dependent on order of operations, due to roundoff error.

Comment: That significantly? I would expect a few last-digits differences, but this is a ~ 0.01% total error or thereabouts. Depending on the application that is rather significant.

Comment: @DoktorSchrott your `MatrixXf M` is a matrix of 10^6 single precision floats. Try with doubles. Also, somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699066/in-which-order-should-floats-be-added-to-get-the-most-precise-result

Comment: @doktorschrott, yes, if you do it 1M times

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your additions are basically a random walk, and the error you make is a different random walk (because you have roundoff error at almost every step). (Note that `Eigen::MatrixXf::Random` fills the matrix with random values in `[-1, 1]`.)

Let's assume that you are, on average, at a float value of `10.0` (estimated only from that single data point you provided). Your epsilon (how much absolute rounding error you will probably make with any addition) is thus around `10.0 * 6e-8` (float epsilon is 2<sup>-23</sup> or about [6e-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon)) or about `6e-7`.

If you do `N = 1000000` random error-accumulation steps of step size `+6e-7` (or `-6e-7`), you have a good chance of ending up at around `sqrt(N) * stepSize = 1000 * 6e-7 = 6e-4` (see [here](http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/152.mf1i.spring02/RandomWalk.htm)), which is not-too-coincidentally close to your 0.01%.

I would similarly estimate an absolute error of `1000 * 10 * 1e-16 = 1e-12` for the addition of 1 million random doubles between -1 and 1 due to floating point precision.

*This is obviously not a rigorous mathematical treatment. It just shows that the error is certainly in the right ballpark.*

The common way to reduce this issue is to sort the floats in order of ascending magnitude before adding them, but you can still be arbitrarily imprecise when doing so. (Example: Keep adding the number `1.0f` to itself - the sum will stop increasing at `2^24` where the epsilon becomes larger than `1.0f`.)