# What is the precision error in this C++ question?

Tags: c++

PROBLEM ::
Whenever a company trades securities, there are various risks involved with the trade. Risk analysis is done for each trade in order to make the maximum profit from that trade.
Each available trade can have the following properties :

```
Probability that the trade will make a profit (p).
Probability that the trade will make a loss (1 - p).
Potential profit of the trade (x).
Potential loss of the trade (y).
```

Find and print the maximum expected amount of money the company can make by performing at most m of the n trades, given the values of m, n, x, y and p.

INPUT FORMAT :::

```
The first line contains two space - separated integers denoting the respective values
n (the number of trades available) and m (the maximum number of trades allowed).

The second line contains space - separated floating - point numbers
describing the respective values of pi,
where each pi denotes the probability that the ith transaction will result in a profit.

The third line contains space - separated floating - point numbers
describing the respective values of xi,
where each xi denotes the potential profit of the ith transaction.

The fourth line contains space - separated floating - point numbers
describing the respective values of yi,
where each yi denotes the potential loss of the ith transaction.
```

CONSTRAINTS :::

```
1 ≤ n, m ≤ 100000
0 ≤ x, y ≤ 100
0 ≤ p ≤ 1
All x, y and p are floating - point numbers
scaled to exactly two decimal places  (i.e 2.45 format).
```

OUTPUT FORMAT :::

Print the maximum expected amount of money that can be made by performing at most m of the n available trades. Scale your answer to exactly 2 decimal places.

EXAMPLE 1::

```
Input ::
    4 2
    0.50 0.50 0.50 0.50
    4.00 1.00 2.00 3.00
    4.00 0.50 1.00 1.00
Output ::
    1.50
i.e. There are n = 4 transactions available and we can perform at most m = 2 of them.
If third and fourth transactions are performed, the expected amount of money made is:
(0.5 * 2.0) - ((1 - 0.5) * 1.0) + (0.5 * 3.0) - ((1 - 0.5) * 1.0) = 1.5.
Since this is greater than all of the other possibilities, 1.50 is our answer.
```

EXAMPLE 2 ::

```
Input ::
    2 2
    0.90 0.50
    1.00 0.50
    100.00 0.40
Output ::
    0.05
i.e. There are n = 2 transactions available and we can perform at most m = 2 of them.
If the second transaction is performed, the expected amount of money made is:
(0.5 * 0.5) - ((1 - 0.5) * 0.4) = 0.05.
Since this is greater than all of the other possibilities we could calculate,
we print 0.05 as our answer.
```

HERE IS MY APPROACH AND C++ PROGRAM ::

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

void maxMoney(int n, int maxtrades, vector<double>& p, vector<double>& x, vector<double>& y)
{
    double profit = 0;
    double t;
    vector<double> v;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        t = p[i] * (x[i] + y[i]) - y[i];
        if (t > 0)
            v.push_back(t);
    }
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), greater<double>());

    int lenn = v.size();
    int siz = min(maxtrades, lenn);
    for (int i = siz - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        profit += v[i];

    // profit = round(profit*100.0)/100.0;   // gives no change in output
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << profit << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    vector<double> p(n), x(n), y(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> p[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> x[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> y[i];

    maxMoney(n, m, p, x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

> ALL the TEST CASES and CONSTRAINTS are verified and correct for this question.

I am getting **maximum** 83 or 84 out of 90 test cases correct, **NOT MORE**, no matter what I do.

Many people answered the problem with *CORRECT SOLUTION (90 / 90 testcases correct).*
So I want to know what is the issue in this and what more improvisation can be done ??

[See the output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y1uH.png)

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7NdQ.png)

Comment: did you test this for corner cases? For example when all investment will most probably will not be profitable.

Comment: @MarekR Yes     if (t > 0) v.push_back(t);      This is checking if trade is profitable or not.

Comment: @TedLyngmo       I have changed the header files, still the output is same.

Comment: Yes, the header file change doesn't change the logic of your program. It only makes it portable so that everyone can compile it.

Comment: Do not use floats for counting money, convert values to the smallest units needed and use integers.

Comment: Unrelated regarding `int siz = min(maxtrades, (int)v.size());`: Instead of casting to `int` you could use `size_t` for all the variables you are using for indexing.

Comment: @Quimby as a principle you are right "you can go to jail for using floats for money", but this is just some online competitive programing, so your suggestion is an overkill.

Comment: @Quimby    I have also tried using int or long long int by static_cast<int>(p) and calculated, but still the output is same.

Comment: If you narrow the scope of your question title to reflect the actual content, it would attract more users.

Comment: Here `t = p[i] * x[i] - (1 - p[i]) * y[i];` you might have a precision loss if `p[i]`  is very small. You might try `t = p[i]*(x[i] + y[i]) - y[i];`

Comment: @Damien    I have changed according to you, but the output is still same.

Comment: @PrabhGill OK. Certainly unrelated: 1. why not passing the vectors by reference (faster) to the function? 2. Why no end-of-line in the `cout`?

Comment: @Damien It is not needed, but i have changed these two, but still the output is same, only speed may differ.

Comment: @zrrbite I have changed the title as mentioned by you. Now can you please remove the downvote.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I have used debugger. But i don't know the test case example in which the code is failing. That's why i asked this question.

Comment: I think you might have to round money values as you go, i.e. before they are summed together. (My approach is commonplace when doing cash flow modelling. Might be the same here although the question doesn't make it clear - not your question, but the problem spec if you get what I mean).

Comment: In the constraints I read *"floating-point numbers scaled to exactly two decimal places"*, it seems to refer to the inputs and output, but chances are that you should round the intermediate calculations too. I'd use integers, BTW.

Comment: And "profit += 0.00002;" is asking for trouble. Kill that.

Comment: @ThomasSablik: Exactly too! The joy of a poor spec, and no real verification of the code by the users or testers. Welcome to my world!!

Comment: @Bathsheba After removing profit+=0.00002, still the output is same.

Comment: @Bob__ I have tried intermediate rounding also, but in that case all testcases have WRONG Answer

Comment: I just realised by `p` is also provided with two digits only. Then, it is possible to perform lossles calculations, by using `int` or maybe `long long int` only. Multiply inputs (`x, y, p`) by 100 and divide results by 1000. `1-p` becomes `100-p`.

Comment: @Damien I have also tried this brother. But maybe there is some precision loss while converting from double*100 to int. I have rounded and use static_cast<long long> too. But the output is still the same.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Codeblocks debugger works for a project and not for single file. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is largely speculation, but you are potentially losing precision by adding the numbers from largest to smallest. You will probably find this works better adding from smallest to largest, or an algorithm such as Kahan summation. Have a look at this question: [In which order should floats be added to get the most precise result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699066/in-which-order-should-floats-be-added-to-get-the-most-precise-result)

As an extremely simplified example, imagine you have decimal floating point numbers with two digits of precision. Imagine you have `[32, 21, 4.3, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, ..., 0.15]` where the number 0.15 repeats 100 times. If you sum from the left, with two digits of precision, you get:

```
        Add           True total  Calculated total   Error
      32                 32              32            0
      21                 53              53            0
       4.3               57.3            57           -0.3
       0.15              57.45           57           -0.45
       0.15              57.6            57           -0.6
       0.15              57.75           57           -0.75
       ...
       0.15              72.3            57          -15.3
```

You can see that none of the small numbers changed the total at all! But there were so many of them, they should have. If you sum from the smallest to the largest then you improve matters a bit, because when you start by adding the small numbers together they are not immediately swamped out by the large numbers, and you have a chance for them to build up to a larger number that *can* affect the total.

Comment: I have edited according to you but the ouput is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

The posed problem creates rounding situations that are difficult for binary floating-point arithmetic.

The problem specification results in currency amounts that are multiplies of .0001 units, because the profits are multiples of .01 currency units and the probabilities are multiples of .01 (unitless), so their products are multiples of .0001 currency units. This means that some ideal results, calculated with real-number arithmetic, will be values such as 7.1350 currency units. However, binary floating-point cannot represent this exactly. In the format commonly used for `double`, IEEE-754 binary64, the nearest representable value is 7.1349999999999997868371792719699442386627197265625. The problem specification also calls for printing results with two decimal places. When that number 7.134999… is rounded to two decimal places, the result is 7.13 because 7.134999… is less than 7.135. However, when 7.1350 is rounded to two decimal places using round-to-nearest ties-to-even or ties-away-from-zero, the result is 7.14. OP’s program would print the former, but the judge may expect the latter.

This can be remedied either by using integer arithmetic scaled appropriately or calculating in double as in the existing code but then using `round(1e4 * ResultAsADouble)` to get an integer result (in the example above, taking 7.134999… to 71350). In either case, the resulting integer should then be divided by 100 and rounded as the judge requires during the division. This produces the desired result in units of .01 currency units, which should then be further divided by 100 for display.

For example, if `x` contains the result as an integer multiple of .0001 currency units, such as 71350, we can set `double y = rint(x/1e2);` or `double y = round(x/1e2);`, according to which rounding method the judge requires. Then `y` will be the desired result as a multiple of .01 currency units, such as 714. The rounding in this case does not fall afoul of binary floating-point because the fraction in the critical case is ½ (*e.g.*, 71350/100 = 713½), which is exactly representable in binary.

Then `y` may be displayed with the required two decimal places using `std::cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << x/1e2 << "\n";`. Although this will involved fractions not exactly representable in binary floating-point, the errors will be too small to affect the result rounded to two decimal places (assuming the C++ implementation uses round-to-nearest ties-to-even, the common default).