# Strange behavior in matrix formation (C++, Armadillo)

Tags: c++, debugging, precision, armadillo

I have a while loop that continues as long as energy variable (type double) has not converged to below a certain threshold. One of the variables needed to calculate this energy is an Armadillo matrix of doubles, named f_mo. In the while loop, this f_mo updates iteratively, so I calculate f_mo at the beginning of each loop as:

```
    arma::mat f_mo = h_core_mo;//h_core_mo is an Armadillo matrix of doubles
    for(size_t p = 0; p < n_mo; p++) {//n_mo is of type size_t
    for(size_t q = 0; q < n_mo; q++) {
        double sum = 0.0;
            for(size_t i = 0; i < n_occ; i++) {//n_occ is of type size_t
                //f_mo(p,q) += 2.0*g_mat_full_qp1_qp1_mo(p*n_mo + q, i*n_mo + i)-g_mat_full_qp1_qp1_mo(p*n_mo+i,i*n_mo+q); //all g_mat_ are Armadillo matrices of doubles
                sum += 2.0*g_mat_full_qp1_qp1_mo(p*n_mo + q, i*n_mo + i)-g_mat_full_qp1_qp1_mo(p*n_mo+i,i*n_mo+q);
            }
            for(size_t i2 = 0; i2 < n_occ2; i2++) {//n_occ2 is of type size_t
                //f_mo(p,q) -= 1.0*g_mat_full_qp1_qp2_mo(p*n_mo + q, i2*n_mo2 + i2);
                sum -= 1.0*g_mat_full_qp1_qp2_mo(p*n_mo + q, i2*n_mo2 + i2);
            }
        
        f_mo(p,q) +=sum;
    }}
```

But say I replace the sum (which I add at the end to f_mo(p,q)) with addition to f_mo(p,q) directly (the commented out code). The output f_mo matrices are identical to machine precision. Nothing about the code should change. The only variables affected in the loop are sum and f_mo. And YET, the code converges to a different energy and in vastly different number of while loop iterations. I am at a loss as to the cause of the difference. When I run the same code 2,3,4,5 times, I get the same result every time. When I recompile with no optimization, I get the same issue. When I run on a different computer (controlling for environment), I yet again get a discrepancy in # of while loops despite identical f_mo, but the total number of iterations for each method (sum += and f_mo(p,q) += ) differ.

It is worth noting that the point at which the code outputs differ is always g_mat_full_qp1_qp2_mo, which is recalculated later in the while loop. HOWEVER, every variable going into the calculation of g_mat_full_qp1_qp2_mo is identical between the two codes. This leads me to think there is something more profound about C++ that I do not understand. I welcome any ideas as to how you would proceed in debugging this behavior (I am all but certain it is not a typical bug, and I've controlled for environment and optimization)

Comment: This could be a precision error. `sum` starts out as zero, so adding small magnitude numbers to 0 will keep the full precision. Because `f_mo(p,q)` has a value in it, adding small magnitude numbers can result in a loss of precision because the lower precision bits get lost. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699066/in-which-order-should-floats-be-added-to-get-the-most-precise-result).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thank you for the tip. I should add that the first iteration where the energy values differ, they differ on the order of 10^-10 (and in the previous iteration they match to 10^-50). Please correct me if my interpretation is wrong, but it therefore seems unlikely to me that this is caused by a precision error.

Comment: Without your code and a [mre] it is only possible to speculate on the cause.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume this a Hartree-Fock, or some other kind of electronic structure calculation where you adding the two-electron integrals to the core Hamiltonian, and apply some domain knowledge.

Part of that assume is the individual elements of the two-electron integrals are very small, in particular compared to the core Hamiltonian.  Hence as 1201ProgramAlarm mentions in their comment, the order of addition will matter.  [You will get a more accurate result if you add smaller numbers together first to avoid loosing precision when adding two numbers many orders of magintude apart.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699066/in-which-order-should-floats-be-added-to-get-the-most-precise-result).  Because you iterate this processes until the Fock matrix `f_mo` has tightly converged you eventually converge to the same value.

In order to add up the numbers in a more accurate order, and hopefully converge faster, **most electronic structure programs have a seperate routine to calculate the two-electron integrals**, and then add them to the core Hamiltonian, which is what you are doing, element by element, in your example code.

[Presentation on numerical computing.](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/courses/moved.Arithmetic/paper.pdf)