# Setting JDialog opacity by Timer

Tags: java, swing, fadein, jdialog, javax.swing.timer

I am using the following code to *fade-in* a `JDialog` with a `javax.swing.Timer`:

```
    float i = 0.0F;
    final Timer timer = new Timer(50, null);
    timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (i == 0.8F){
                timer.stop();
            }
            i = i + 0.1F;
            setOpacity(i);
        }
    });
    timer.start();
```

The `Dialog` is nicely faded-in with the desired effect but at last, an `IllegalArgumentException` Occurs saying that:

```
 The value of opacity should be in the range [0.0f .. 1.0f]
```

But the problem is I am not going far fro `i = 0.8F` so how can it be a illegal argument??
Exception occur at line : `setOpacity(i);`

Any suggestions? Solutions?

Comment: I suggest to review your code as the `i` you are modifying is probably not the one you expect. It cannot be the `final float i = 0.0F;` variable as that one has been made `final`

Comment: sorry for that @Robin, its just a typing mistake of mine, edited this time..as you see if i made it final than it throw a `compiler error` rather than `exception`..thanks for pointing it out.. :)

Comment: Can I ask what is this "setOpacity" method? I'm trying to implement dialog fadein/out too.

Comment: @AurélienRibon Offcourse you can ask..[`setOpacity(float)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setOpacity(float)), it is a method (in Java SE 7) of `java.awt.Frame`, super-class of `JFrame`..

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. I was always trying to maintain a 1.6 compatibility for all my open-source apps, so I never saw this method, but I guess enforcing 1.7 can't really harm users. Plus when Java8 wil come I'll be the first to jump on lambda expressions :) Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that you're dealing with floating point numbers and `==` doesn't work well with them since you cannot accurately depict 0.8 in floating point, and so your Timer will never stop.

Use `>=`.  Or better still, only use int.

i.e.,

```
int timerDelay = 50; // msec
new Timer(timerDelay, new ActionListener() {
    private int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        counter++;
        if (counter == 10){
            ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
        }
        setOpacity(counter * 0.1F);
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Wow! thats it...easy and useful..thanks very much! Well one thing more, is it legal to do this thing? I mean using Timer and fading-in dialog, i hope it is not going against standard Swing coding standards?

Comment: I don't know of any "standards" with regards to this, or any Swing standards for that measure, just caveats with regards to threading, and I don't see this as stepping on threads.

Comment: yes my concern is with swing Threading Model and EDT things, I hope its not disturbing them,because i like this little tweak of mine very much :-)

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257166/java-floats-and-doubles-how-to-avoid-that-0-0-0-1-0-1-0-9000001) discussion how to do addition for correct float precision

Comment: @mprab: all he needs here though is to use ints.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i am using `float` with `>=` sign, as with `int` there will be only `8` opacity levels, which is kind of less in fading-in effect..

Comment: @Asif: What I suggest though for count accuracy is to use ints as your loop counter and then use the int to create the float inside the loop for your opacity parameter. You can't beat the accuracy of an int.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels you forgot `i` here. . .please do edit considering `i` too