# JDialog : Making some portion transparent

Tags: java, swing, transparency, jdialog

I have a JDialog which gets open once you click on a Button. I wanted to show an arrow indicator towards the button when the JDialog gets opened. For this I require extreme portion of JDialog (towards the Button) to be transparent so that I can paint or add an Image of arrow.

How can I make the JDialog a transparent Dialog with some portion as transparent.

Answer (score 1):

[Setting JDialog opacity by Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290878/setting-jdialog-opacity-by-timer)

this might help you. In general method `setOpacity()` is the one you want