# Precise sum of floating point numbers

Tags: algorithm, floating-point, sum, floating-accuracy

I am aware of [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257166/java-floats-and-doubles-how-to-avoid-that-0-0-0-1-0-1-0-9000001), but I want to ask for people opinion on my algorithm to sum floating point numbers as accurately as possible with practical costs.

Here is my first solution:

```
put all numbers into a min-absolute-heap. // EDIT as told by comments below
pop the 2 smallest ones.
add them.
put the result back into the heap.
continue until there is only 1 number in the heap.
```

This one would take O(n*logn) instead of normal O(n). Is that really worth it?

The second solution comes from the characteristic of the data I'm working on.
It is a huge list of **positive** numbers with **similar order of magnitude**.

```
a[size]; // contains numbers, start at index 0
for(step = 1; step < size; step<<=1)
    for(i = step-1; i+step<size; i+=2*step)
        a[i+step] += a[i];
    if(i < size-1)
        a[size-1] += a[i];
```

The basic idea is to do sum in a 'binary tree' fashion.

Note: it's a pseudo C code. `step<<=1` means multiply step by 2.
This one would take O(n).
I feel like there might be a better approach. Can you recommend/criticize?

Comment: It seems that you are implicitly assuming the numbers to sum are positive. If they could be of different signs, a strategy would be something like “adding the number of smallest magnitude and of sign opposite to the current count, if possible”.

Comment: Oh, yes. I did assume that my numbers are positive. Editing the question now. Thanks.

Comment: are you assuming the numbers in your second example are sorted?

Comment: The elements will be put into the heap in increasing order, so you can use two queues instead. This produces `O(n)` if the numbers are pre-sorted

Comment: @AShelly No, I did not assume that the numbers are sorted.

Comment: @JanDvorak Though, my specific list is not pre-sorted. I'm still interested in how using 2 queues can make it O(n) in that case. Still can't imagine it.

Comment: When choosing algorithms consider the following set of numbers: `{DBL_MAX, 1, -DBL_MAX}`. If all your algorithm does is decide what order to sum the numbers in, then it gets the incorrect answer `0` unless it adds the two *large* numbers first, in which case it gets the correct answer `1`. So, your min-heap fails for that particular input, as for that matter do most heuristics for this job. Kahan gets it right, I think.

Comment: @Billiska posted as an answer.

Comment: Your 2nd algorithm is also O(N lg N).  It goes through all the elements, then half the elements, then half again....  It has the same runtime as this simpler equivalent: `j=size-1; while(j>0) for(i=0;i<j;) a[i++]+=a[j--];`

Comment: @AShelly My second algorithm is not O(N lg N) but O(N) because in the first 'step loop' it adds N/2 times, the second time it adds N/4 times, the third time it adds N/8 times, and so on

Comment: @AShelly: `n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ... = 2*n`

Comment: oops.  This is what happens when an aerospace engineer attempts to do computer science..

Comment: @hammar: well, might be `2*n` depending what order you add the terms ;-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Kahan's summation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) is significantly more precise than straightforward summation, and it runs in O(n) (somewhere between 1-4 times slower than straightforward summation depending how fast floating-point is compared to data access. Definitely less than 4 times slower on desktop hardware, and without any shuffling around of data).

---

Alternately, if you are using the usual x86 hardware, and if your compiler allows access to the 80-bit `long double` type, simply use the straightforward summation algorithm with the accumulator of type `long double`. Only convert the result to `double` at the very end.

---

If you really need a lot of precision, you can combine the above two solutions by using `long double` for variables `c`, `y`, `t`, `sum` in Kahan's summation algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for recommending Kahan's algorithm. Let me read it a bit and I'll come back to accept the answer.

Comment: How does Kahan summation with double precision internally compare to plain quad precision?

Comment: @MartinUeding It's possible to build sequences that sum more precisely with each of them. For an “ordinary” sequence of many values of the same sign and magnitude, quad-precision is slightly more precise, because the significand of quand-precision is slightly more than twice that of double-precision.

Answer (score 9):

If you are concerned about reducing the numerical error in your summation then you may be interested in [Kahan's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm).

Comment: Thank you for recommending Kahan's algorithm. I'm new to stackoverflow, what do you do if there's 2 same answer?

Comment: Study the same thing twice ?

Comment: @Billiska generally the most complete/helpful is accepted but you can still upvote other helpful anwers

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that your binary decomposition will work almost as well as Kahan summation.

Here is an example to illustrate it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>

void sumpair( float *a, float *b)
{
    volatile float sum = *a + *b;
    volatile float small = sum - std::max(*a,*b);
    volatile float residue = std::min(*a,*b) - small;
    *a = sum;
    *b = residue;
}

void sumpairs( float *a,size_t size, size_t stride)
{
    if (size <= stride*2 ) {
        if( stride<size )
            sumpair(a+i,a+i+stride);
    } else {
        size_t half = 1;
        while(half*2 < size) half*=2;;
        sumpairs( a , half , stride );
        sumpairs( a+half , size-half , stride );
    }
}

void sumpairwise( float *a,size_t size )
{
    for(size_t stride=1;stride<size;stride*=2)
        sumpairs(a,size,stride);
}

int main()
{
    float data[10000000];
    size_t size= sizeof data/sizeof data[0];
    for(size_t i=0;i<size;i++) data[i]=((1<<30)*-1.0+random())/(1.0+random());

    float naive=0;
    for(size_t i=0;i<size;i++) naive+=data[i];
    printf("naive      sum=%.8g\n",naive);

    double dprec=0;
    for(size_t i=0;i<size;i++) dprec+=data[i];
    printf("dble prec  sum=%.8g\n",(float)dprec);

    sumpairwise( data , size );
    printf("1st approx sum=%.8g\n",data[0]);
    sumpairwise( data+1 , size-1);
    sumpairwise( data , 2 );
    printf("2nd approx sum=%.8g\n",data[0]);
    sumpairwise( data+2 , size-2);
    sumpairwise( data+1 , 2 );
    sumpairwise( data , 2 );
    printf("3rd approx sum=%.8g\n",data[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

I declared my operands volatile and compiled with -ffloat-store to avoid extra precision on x86 architecture

```
g++  -ffloat-store  -Wl,-stack_size,0x20000000 test_sum.c
```

and get: (0.03125 is 1ULP)

```
naive      sum=-373226.25
dble prec  sum=-373223.03
1st approx sum=-373223
2nd approx sum=-373223.06
3rd approx sum=-373223.06
```

This deserve a little explanation.

- I first display naive summation
- Then double precision summation (Kahan is roughly equivalent to that)
- The 1st approximation is the same as your binary decomposition. Except that I store the sum in data[0] and that I care of storing residues. This way, the exact sum of data before and after summation is unchanged
- This enables me to approximate the error by summing the residues at 2nd iteration in order to correct the 1st iteration (equivalent to applying Kahan on binary summation)
- By iterating further I can further refine the result and we see a convergence

Answer (score 1):

The elements will be put into the heap in increasing order, so you can use two queues instead. This produces O(n) if the numbers are pre-sorted.

This pseudocode produces the same results as your algorithm and runs in `O(n)` if the input is pre-sorted and the sorting algorithm detects that:

```
Queue<float> leaves = sort(arguments[0]).toQueue();
Queue<float> nodes = new Queue();

popAny = #(){
       if(leaves.length == 0) return nodes.pop();
  else if(nodes.length == 0) return leaves.pop();
  else if(leaves.top() > nodes.top()) return nodes.pop();
  else return leaves.pop();
}

while(leaves.length>0 || nodes.length>1) nodes.push(popAny()+popAny());

return nodes.pop();
```

Comment: I implemented both the Kahan summation algorithm and sort-then-sum using float (32-bit IEEE 754) and compared them to the result obtained using double (64-bit) to sum 1024 numbers selected randomly and uniformly from [0, 1). I ran a few dozen trials. In some, Kahan and sort returned the same value. In most, Kahan had less error. In none did sorting produce less error.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I was replying to the asker's comment `I'm still interested in how using 2 queues can make it O(n) in that case. Still can't imagine it.`

Comment: @JanDvorak Closer inspection. The maximum number of elements in `node` queue can reach N/2 with this input = {k,k+1,k+2,...,2*k} where k is positive. Hence, your algorithm is O(N/2 lg N/2) which is the same as O(N lg N).

Comment: @Billiska Inserting an element into a queue is a constant time operation. Removing an element from a queue is a constant time operation. The while loop will run exactly `N-1` times. The while loop by itself is linear in the number of elements. The only non-linear step is the sorting step.

Comment: Elaborating about the queue: If you don't care about the space, a queue is `{data=[], start=0, end=0, push=#(x){data[end++]=x}, pop=#(){if(start==end) die(); return data[start++]}}`

Comment: A linked-list queue is also constant-time: `{head:null, tail:null, push=#(x){if(tail){tail.next={data:x,next:null}; tail=tail.next}else{head=tail={data:x}, pop:#(){if(!head) die(); var r=head; head=head.next; if(!head) tail=null; return r};`

Comment: I see. That's something we think of differently. Because I think that the sum of 2 smallest element can still be large compared to the rest of the inputs. That's why in the original solution I put addition result back into the 'heap' which is a O(lg N) operation.

Comment: That's why I suggest two queues. A queue has constant-time ops.

Comment: At each step, I take either one of the original values or one of the new values, whichever is lower. The original values get sorted in a separate step and the new values get created in ascending order.

Comment: Well, it's now a different algorithm. the order of summing will be different for the same input. But indeed, yours will do things in O(N).

Comment: @Billiska My algorithm computes the same sums as your algorithm.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19652/discussion-between-billiska-and-jan-dvorak)