# How to iterate between 0.1f and 1.0f with 0.1f increments in Java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java floats and doubles, how to avoid that 0.0 + 0.1 + … + 0.1 == 0.9000001?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257166/java-floats-and-doubles-how-to-avoid-that-0-0-0-1-0-1-0-9000001)

I am having a following problem in Java - I need to iterate between 0.1f and 1.0f in 0.1f increments,so I would like my output to look like this:

```
    0.1
    0.2
    0.3
    0.4
    ...
    0.9
```

Instead,when I do:

```
for(float i = 0.1f; i < 1f; i += 0.1f)
    System.out.println(i);
```

I get

```
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.70000005
0.8000001
0.9000001
```

I imagine it has something to do with the way fractions are represented by a computer,but I would like to know why is this,and if there is anything I can do to stop it.
thanks.

Comment: Can you use a double instead?

Comment: This is not doable at all, really.  There is no exact value `0.1` representable as a float _or_ a double.

Comment: *"I would like to know why is this"* - Short answer is "rounding error".  For a long answer, read this - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html.  *"... and if there is anything I can do to stop it"* - Short answer "nope".

Answer (score 6):

Use integers in your for loop to avoid repeated floating point math, which compounds floating-point errors.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
   float f = (float) i / 10.0f;
   System.err.println(f);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    System.out.println(i/10f);
```

```
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
```

What you are seeing is a product of inaccuracies that are intrinsic to floats, which naturally build up if you add them continuously, as you do in the code you posted. If we use `int`s in the loop instead, we avoid the float-addition and, therefore, also the error build-up.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted this answer, but if I were to guess, because your output starts with 0.0, not 0.1.

Comment: @rgettman Ah yes - 1 character change, thanks for pointing it out. I really wish downvoters would comment to indicate such things.

Answer (score 0):

floats are binary, and don't represent decimals well

if applicable Iterate in 1/8ths or  0.125 instead.

Answer (score -2):

```
for(float i =1.0f;i<10f;i+=1f)
System.out.println(i/10f);`
```

is ugly as hell but works here (Ubuntu AMD64 OpenJDK)

Comment: To quote myself: it is ugly as hell, but it works here.

Comment: Hmmm ... looks / sounds like a voodoo solution to me.

Comment: To quote myself: it is ugly as hell, but it works here

Comment: ... provided you keep sacrificing the chickens!!  "It seems to work" without a clear understanding of why is a recipe for fragile unmaintainable code.  We should be *discouraging* this approach to programming in new programmers ... rather than offering them our own voodoo programming "solutions" to copy into their code.

Comment: Exatlcy. You may substitute cursed ducks, if no chickens are available. This is what I ment by "but works here (Ubuntu AMD64 OpenJDK)": I don't know, if it would work on x86 (and I don't care). The understanding of what happens is trivial: 1/10 is not representable in any binary floating point number, regardless of precision. I don't encourage anybody (experienced or not) to try and make 0.1 an exact float .. it just won't work. What I do say is: This works under the exact circumstances specified. Not a bit more.