# Java- double variable issue

Tags: java, double

Here's my simple equations counter.Now it counts equations with two variables.It's based on trying many combinations (4 milion or 16 milion) of `a` and `b` variables.So the code works well and it counts exact.But since I tried to change variable `b` to double, things go wrong.I've expected line `b=b+0.1` secures setting variable `b` each 10th time to 1.0.But almost imidiately after start way more decimal numbers appear for each `b`.So do I use wrong datatype? Or should I raise variable `b` by different value?(I also tried changing all variables to double).Thank you for suggestions!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Buffer{
static int a;
static double b;
static BufferedReader reader;
static String query;
static int range;
static int result;

public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
    reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.print("Choose speed of test(fast or slow):");
    query=reader.readLine();

    if(query.equals("fast"))
        range=2000;
    else
        range=4000;

     //START THE TEST//       
    while((a+b)!=26000){
        b=b+0.1;
        if(b==range+1){
            b=0;
            a=a+1;
        }
        if((a+b)!=26000)
            System.out.println("a- "+a+", "+"b- "+b+"=false.");

        if((a+b)==26000){
            System.out.println("a- "+a+", "+"b- "+b+"=true.");
            System.out.println("\n"+"Done.You can possibly solve this equation, if a= "+a+" and b= "+b+".");
        }
        if(a==range&&b==range&&(a+b)!=26000){
            System.out.println("\n"+"Tested "+a*b+" options.Solution not found.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: This could help you [Double increments in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832864/double-increments-in-java)

Comment: Congratulations, you are the 1,000,000th person to run in a [double precision issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). If you want exact values use a `BigDecimal`.

Comment: And, when dealing with a floating-point representation, never (unless you absolutely know what you're doing) use `==` to compare -- always compare for `>=` or whatever when doing a loop index test, etc.

Comment: (Simply do `if(b>=range+1)` (and the equivalent for your other tests) and your code will probably work (better), without further modification.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use BigDecimal instead of float/double primitives to avoid those issues. Some of which are described here: [Java Mistake 1 - Using float and double for monetary or financial calculation](http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.at/2012/02/java-mistake-1-using-float-and-double.html)

Answer (score 1):

The issue you deal with is [representation error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). Type double can not represent some values.

Typical solution for this situation is usage of BigDecimal or Integer type.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone here, did give you an alternative solution, but I think you should understand, why did the datatype `double` did not work for you.

The problem lies with `Binary representation`. For decimals is not represented to the exact form.
Say for example:

`10 is represented as 1010 in binary` **but**,

`0.10 is 0.00011001100110011001100110011001 and still going on.....`

Hence the error occurs in double. As suggested by others, opt for BigDecimal.

You can also learn more about the same, through these links;

[Rounding Errors](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/202843/solutions-for-floating-point-rounding-errors)

[Addition Of Doubles](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/205351/addition-of-doubles-is-not-equal-to-sum-of-the-double-as-a-whole)

Hope that helps.