# why 0.3+0.3+0.3 = 0.899999999999999 in java?

Tags: java, double

In my Java class.
My teacher has asked this question.
Can anyone help me out, I would appreciate it. TY.

**why**

```
0.3+0.3+0.3 = 0.899999999999999
```

in java   ?????

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/5257166/4405757

Comment: oh data types data types. It's because of precision problems.

Answer (score 1):

Its because of floating point precision errors. The reason is that these data types are built for fast and accurate approximations and not for exact results. For that we use *BigDecimal*

For more info
[Java Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)
[Java Float Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3)