# How this implicit type conversion works in java?

Tags: java, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

### Why the output of adding a double value with a float value in Java results in a double value which has more number of digits after decimal points than the input itself?

*Why the digits after decimal points increased and who is supplying this additional value after the decimal points?*

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        double data = 444.324; 
        float value = 5.1f; 
        System.out.println(value+data);   
    } 
}
```

Mathematically speaking the output should have been

```
449.424
```

*right?*
But the output of the following program is

```
449.4239999046326
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: the same thing is solved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257166/how-to-avoid-floating-point-precision-errors-with-floats-or-doubles-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Noone is supplying the digits. You are just seeing rounding errors because floating point numbers cannot be accurately represented in computer memory.

Google floating point errors for more information.